# Freewall.js only loads after resize

Tags: javascript, html, freewalljs

I'm using freewall.js for displaying a grid on my frontpage. But it doesn't work correct. It only loads after resize. And also after the resize it calculates false heights and puts some objects on other places where they shouldn't be.

Here's my JS:

```
$(function(){
    var wall = new Freewall(".freewall");
    wall.reset({
        selector: '.freewall-item',
        animate: false,
        cellW: 150,
        cellH: 'auto',
        gutterY: 15,
        gutterX: 15,
        onResize: function() {
            wall.fitWidth();
        }
    });

    wall.container.find('.event-intro-image').load(function() {
        wall.fitWidth();
    });

    $(window).trigger('resize');
});
```

As you can see i also tried to use `$(window).trigger('resize');`, without sucess.

Comment: call this `wall.fitWidth();` after calling reset method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The function gets now called on page load, but the position of the elements is only correct after resize

Comment: Could you share jsfiddle link?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/StaXter/hym067og/13/